# Knex query with join - works with .where but not with .whereRaw

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

I am using knex and objection.js to work with my postgres database. I have this query involving three different tables and different possible filters. 
The problem I have is when I do a left join and query with .whereRaw, I get the following error: 
error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "publication"
If I use .where instead, it works. However I need the whereRaw to make the filter not case-sensitive.

```
      Reader.query(Reader.knex())
        .where('Reader.id', '=', readerId)        
        .eager('[tags, publications.[tags, attributions]]')
        .modifyEager('publications', builder => {
          if (filter.title) {
            const title = filter.title.toLowerCase()
            builder.where('Publication.name', 'like', `%${title}%`)
            // builder.whereRaw(
            //  'LOWER(name) LIKE ?',
            //   '%' + filter.title.toLowerCase() + '%'
            // )
          }
          if (filter.attribution || filter.author) {
              builder.leftJoin(
              'Attribution',
              'Attribution.publicationId',
              '=',
              'Publication.id'
            )
          }
          if (filter.author) {
            builder
              .where('Attribution.normalizedName', '=', author)
              .andWhere('Attribution.role', '=', 'author')
          }
          if (filter.attribution) {
            builder.where(
              'Attribution.normalizedName',
              'like',
              `%${attribution}%`
            )
            if (filter.role) {
              builder.andWhere('Attribution.role', '=', filter.role)
            }
          }
          orderBuilder(builder)
          builder.limit(limit)
          builder.offset(offset)
        })
```

The commmented out .whereRaw query is the one I want to make work. 
What is different between the .where and .whereRaw that would cause one to work and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `whereRaw` is not working, would have to do some debugging to find out, but you could use `ilike` for case insensitive search with `where`
Example:

`` builder.where('Publication.name', 'ilike', `%${title}%`) ``

[Reference](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/2009)